# Is it possible to automatically add value to form submission in symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I would like to know if I can automatically add values ​​when submitting a form under symfony?

For Exemple

Entity Product

```
private ref;
private price;
private quantity;
private total;
```

ProductType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
 $builder
 ->add('ref')
 ->add('price')
 ->add('quantity')
 ...
 ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {

  $form = $event->getForm();
  $product = $event->getData();

  $v = $product['price'] * $product['quantity'];

  $form->add('total');
  $form->get('total')->setData($v);
 }
```

ProductController

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

**dd($form->getData());**
```

I would like to retrieve all the values ​​entered in $form->getData():
-ref
-price
-quantity
-total(automatic addition of this field with its value)

I still don't understand how it works despite my readings. Is it possible ?

I never get all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you have the Product entity (or simply class). So you can make a getter that returns the value of `price * quantity` and call it on your controller after form submitting.

```
class Product {
    private $ref;
    private $price;
    private $quantity;

    // getters and setters or another logic what you need

    public function getTotal() {
        return $this->price * $this->quantity;
    }
}
```

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('ref')
            ->add('price')
            ->add('quantity');
        
        // other code
    }
}
```

```
class ProductController extends AbstractController {
    public function __invoke(Request $request) {
        $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dd($product->getTotal());
        }
        
        // other code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
$form->add('total');
$form->get('total')->setData($v);
```

to

```
$product['total'] = $product['price'] * $product['quantity'];
```

and change the event to `POST_SUBMIT`

Moreoever, take a look at [`data_class`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes) attribute if you want to bind, directly, a form to an object